# Home Network Speed Control

Tags: networking, internet, speed

I have a home network installed in following way:
Internet<->server<->switch<->computers,etc

Server has DHCP server installed and I would like to be able to limit download&upload speed for each client connected to server via switch.

Anyone can suggest good free software to do that?

Comment: I think this is going to depend on the switch you have.

Comment: Edit your question and add the operating system you use.

Comment: I am running Windows Server 2003 64bit

Answer (score 0):

If server is running linux, then you could do this with iptables.